# Объект __ge__ при перегрузке

Tags: python, классы, методы, перегрузка-операторов

Есть код:

```
class MyList:
    used = False
    def prepare():
        def passed(name):
            keys = object.__dict__.keys()
            return not name in keys
        for name in list.__dict__:
            if passed(name):
                print(name, "-", list.__dict__[name])
                attr = getattr(list, name)
                def func(self, *args, **kwargs):
                    print(name, "<--------")                
                    return attr(self.obj, *args, **kwargs)
                setattr(__class__, name, func)

    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
        if not __class__.used: 
            __class__.prepare()
            __class__.used = True
```

Этот класс должен при первом выполнении метода **init**, сам присвоить себе объекты класса **list**. В результате должен был получиться класс полностью копирующий своим поведением **list**. Не спрашивайте почему я просто не обернул объект класса, мне это действительно было нужно.
Но на практике, при выполнении следующего кода:

```
obj = MyList([1, 2])
obj0 = MyList([22, 33])
print(obj, obj0)
obj.reverse()
obj0.reverse()
obj.append(1)
obj0.append(1)
```

весь вывод заканчивается на этом:

```
__ge__ <--------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 29, in <module>
    obj.reverse()
  File "file.py", line 17, in func
    return attr(self.obj, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: expected 1 arguments, got 0
```

Решить эту проблему я так и не смог, поэтому я прошу у тебя помощи, Stack Overflow. Обьясни в чем дело, и как это решить.

Comment: Почему не обернули вокруг `list`?

Comment: @0andriy В этом состоит суть задания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        def func(self, *args, name=name, attr=attr, **kwargs):
            print(name, attr, "<--------")
            return attr(self.obj, *args, **kwargs)
```